# CakePHP: parsing data in view

Tags: parsing, email, class, cakephp, view

I currently have a class that generates an object from rawtext of an email. You can get body, subject and etc from that object.

My question is, in the cakephp system where should I put that class. Is it an helper, component? The important thing is, is that object should be created for each mail. I have an view that show all the mails of each topic.

With an foreach loop I loop all related mails containing the rawtext.

Do you have any idea what the best thing to do is?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation suggests to put all your third party code in vendors folder. you can import any class from there with:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'myfile');
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files